# How to remove all characters after a certain index from a string

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to remove all characters from a string after a specified index. I am sure there must be a simple function to do this, but I'm not sure what it is. I am basically looking for the javascript equivalent of c#'s string.Remove.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var myStr = "asdasrasdasd$hdghdfgsdfgf";
myStr = myStr.split("$")[0];
```

or

```
var myStr = "asdasrasdasd$hdghdfgsdfgf";
myStr = myStr.substring(0, myStr.indexOf("$") - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. Will accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 3):

Use substring

```
var x = 'get this test';
alert(x.substr(0,8)); //output: get this
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for this.

```
string.substring(from, to)

from : Required. The index where to start the extraction. First character is at index 0
to  : Optional. The index where to stop the extraction. If omitted, it extracts the rest of the string
```

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `slice` as you can use negative positions for the index. It's tidier code in general. For example:

```
var s = "messagehere";
var message = s.slice(0, -4);
```